# Regex to find last occurrence between the braces

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I need regex expression to be used in JavaScript/ES6 to find the value between last occurrence of brackets in a String

for Example if these are the sample Strings:

- "Some Sample String (Value 1) (more) Something (Value 2)"
- "Some Sample String (Val One), Something (Val Two) "
- "Some Sample String (VOne) - Something (VTwo)"

the regex expression should return the following values respectively from the above Strings

- "Value 2"
- "Val Two"
- "VTwo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex replace all approach.  We can match on the pattern `^.*\((.*?)\).*$`, which will consume everything from the start of the input up to, but not including, the final `(...)` term.  We then capture the contents of that term and print out to the console.

```js
var input = "Some Sample String (Value 1) (more) Something (Value 2)";
var last = input.match(/\(.*\)/) ? input.replace(/^.*\((.*?)\).*$/, "$1") : "NO MATCH";
console.log(last);
```

Note that I do an initial check with `match` to ensure that the term has at least one `(...)` term.  If so, then we take the regex replacement, otherwise we assign `NO MATCH`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this solution is working perfectly in my use case.

Answer (score 2):

`str.match(/.*\((.*)\).*$/)[1]`

Works for your use cases.

limit: This doesn't work for the strings which have nested brakets.
eg. "(Some Sample String (VOne) - Something (VTwo))"

Comment: you could also write `/.*\(([^()]+)\)/` to handle nesting in a sensible way